Why are callback APIs preferred over sync APIs for a GRPC C++ client?
The gRPC documentation for C++ states to use callback API in favor of other APIs for most RPCs:
https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/#c
I compared
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_client.cc
with:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_callback_client.cc
I am trying to understand why the callback example is better. It delegates the work to a different thread but the main thread is just sleeping and waiting for it. This is the callback code:
// The actual RPC.
std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool done = false;
Status status;
stub_->async()->SayHello(&context, &request, &reply,
                         [&mu, &cv, &done, &status](Status s) {
                           status = std::move(s);
                           std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
                           done = true;
                           cv.notify_one();
                         });

std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
while (!done) {
  cv.wait(lock);
}

While this is the sync code:
// The actual RPC.
Status status = stub_->SayHello(&context, request, &reply);

Aren’t you making the callback api example possibly slower to run due to thread overhead?

Example code is often simplified to the point of being "bad". Real uses would have the main thread doing something else, rather than waiting on cv

The Sync API is blocking, which means you'll need to move the calls to a separate thread separately to avoid blocking the main thread - their example is confusing because they block the main thread anyway, but they do this to wait for the callback to be called.
The callback API is inherently concurrent, so your main thread will not be blocked until the response is resolved.
You said: "It delegates the work to a different thread but the main thread is just sleeping and waiting for it.", but this is not true. I believe the async API is only concurrent on the thread you call it on. Internally, it uses a CompletionQueue api to handle messages.
They explain this in the link you posted btw:

Favor callback API over other APIs for most RPCs, given that the application can avoid all blocking operations or blocking operations can be moved to a separate thread. The callback API is easier to use than the completion-queue async API but is currently slower for truly high-QPS workloads.


Thanks for your reply. What I meant with the sleeping is that in this particular example the main thread holds in cv.wait(...) until the callback sets the done flag.

That's correct - but in a real application, instead of sleeping, you can do other things.
